# npmのパッケージnpm-check-updatesでエラーがでる

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

npmパッケージの更新に「npm-check-updates」というのが便利だと言うことで導入しました。
ところが，「ncu」コマンドを実行してもエラーが出て更新できませんでした。
ログに解決策としてgithubのURLが出るのですが，恥ずかしながら英語に疎いためよくわかりませんでした。
このエラーの原因は何でしょうか？

```
$ ncu
Hmmmmm... this is taking a long time. Your console is telling me to wait forinput
on stdin, but maybe that is not what you want.
Try specifying a package file explicitly with --packageFile package.json.
See https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates/issues/136#issuecomment-155721102
```

環境
Windows10 1607
Node.js v7.5.0
nodist v0.8.8
npm v4.2.0

Comment: ryo.kさん，unarist♦ さん，回答ありがとうございました。返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。色々と試してみたところ，node,jsをnodist経由でなく直接インストールして環境を構築し直したら，無事使えるようになりました。

Answer (score 1):

node.js を nod‌​ist 経由でなく直接インストールして環境‌​を構築し直したら，無事使えるようになりま‌​した。 <sub>([質問投稿者のコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32757/npm%E3%81%AE%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8npm-check-updates%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%82%8B#comment33210_32757)より)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

原因は不明で申し訳ないのですが、package.jsonが見つからないようです。

> Try specifying a package file explicitly with --packageFile
>   package.json.

package.jsonを明示するように書かれていますので、下記のコマンドを試してみてはいかがでしょうか。こちらの環境でも同じエラーがでたのですが、下記コマンドで解決しました。

```
$ ncu --packageFile package.json
```

Comment: ncuは `cat package.json | ncu` のようにパイプ経由での読み込みにも対応していて、パイプでなくコンソールからの入力と判定できる場合のみpackage.jsonを読み込むようです。で、CygwinやMinGWで使われる端末エミュレータ（内部的にパイプでやりとりしてるので本物のコンソールではない）などの一部環境では誤判定してパイプ入力を待ってしまう…という。